# How to convert mol m-2 s-1 CO2 emission to Megaton day-1 (MtCO2 per day)?

Tags: climate-models, co2, greenhouse-gases

I am working on the global CO<sub>2</sub> emission using a model dataset. The model provides the CO<sub>2</sub> emission in mol m<sup>-2</sup> s<sup>-1</sup>. How to convert mol m<sup>-2</sup> s<sup>-1</sup> CO<sub>2</sub> emission to Megaton day<sup>-1</sup> (Mt per day)?

Regards

Comment: You don't have enough information.  You have a flux rate, so without a defined area, you can't convert to daily emissions.  You can easily convert moles to Mt, and seconds to days, but you still need an area defined.

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer solved the problem. There was a global dataset, and the area was 510.1 million km².

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the calculation for 1 mol of CO$_2$

1 mol of CO$_2$ weighs 49 grammes = 0.0049 kg

86400 seconds in a day, so 864000 * 0.0049 = 423.36 kg/day/m$^2$

The surface area of the globe is 5.1 x 10$^{14}$ m$^2$ - so 423.6 * 5.1 x 10$^{14}$ = 2.16 x 10$^{17}$ kg/day

Convert from kg to Megatons, 10$^9$ kg in a Megaton  - so we get 1 mol CO$_2$/m$^2$/second = 2.16 x 10$^8$ Megatons/day

This assumes, as farrenthorpe commented, that the molar emission rate represents a rate evenly distributed over the globe - if, for instance it only represented terrestrial emissions, or emissions in a particular region the calculation would need to take that into account.

Comment: Thank you sir for explaining in detail. It helped out.

Comment: Farhan - happy to help out. I just edited my answer as I had made an error in units that changed the answer. I  missed conversion from square metres to square kilometres!